# Get error "unknown field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend" when switch from v1beta1 to v1 in Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I had the below YAML for my Ingress and it worked (and continues to work):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test-layer
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mylocalhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: test-app
              servicePort: 5000
```

However, it tells me that it's deprecated and I should change to using `networking.k8s.io/v1`. When I do that (see below) it throws an error.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test-layer
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mylocalhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: test-app
              servicePort: 5000
```

**ERROR**

```
error: error validating "test-ingress.yaml": 
  error validating data: [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): 
    unknown field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend, 
    ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): 
      unknown field "servicePort" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend]; 
      if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Other than changing the API version, I made no other changes.

`kubectl version` returns:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", GitCommit:"e19964183377d0ec2052d1f1fa930c4d7575bd50", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-26T14:30:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", GitCommit:"e19964183377d0ec2052d1f1fa930c4d7575bd50", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-26T14:23:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 297, accepted):

I think that this [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/89778) contains the change you're asking about.

```
`Ingress` and `IngressClass` resources have graduated to `networking.k8s.io/v1`. Ingress and IngressClass types in the `extensions/v1beta1` and `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` API versions are deprecated and will no longer be served in 1.22+. Persisted objects can be accessed via the `networking.k8s.io/v1` API. Notable changes in v1 Ingress objects (v1beta1 field names are unchanged):
* `spec.backend` -> `spec.defaultBackend`
* `serviceName` -> `service.name`
* `servicePort` -> `service.port.name` (for string values)
* `servicePort` -> `service.port.number` (for numeric values)
* `pathType` no longer has a default value in v1; "Exact", "Prefix", or "ImplementationSpecific" must be specified
Other Ingress API updates:
* backends can now be resource or service backends
* `path` is no longer required to be a valid regular expression
```

If you look in the [1.19 Ingress doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), it looks like the new syntax would be:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

I unfortunately don't have a 1.19 cluster to test myself, but I think this is what you're running into.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it's right. Wish they'd update the high level documentation to match

Comment: How can they put such a breaking change in these config files! Cannot imagine the nightmaare for those in charge to maintain many complex deployment structures on kubernetes!

Comment: @lyrio Because it was only in beta before and now it's a full version. Notice before it was `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` and now it's the released version `networking.k8s.io/v1`

Comment: It works well - note for GKE users - the ingress update takes about 5 - 10 minutes WITH DOWNTIME on static ip

Comment: I <3 U, this help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was recently struggling with the same issue. I was creating older versions of nginx resource with new apiVersion. This post helped. giving my older version ingress file for reference.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: older-ingress
 namespace: ing-internal
 annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
 ingressClassName: nginx-example
 rules:
 - http:
     paths:
     - path: /hi
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         serviceName: hi
         servicePort: 1234
```

Answer (score -11):

Please try the following:

```
% minikube addons enable dashboard
% minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

Then, change the `apiVersion` in `dashboard-ingress.yaml` to:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Comment: Hi Abdul.  Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for contributing.  When your answer is downvoted, this can be discouraging.  Don't let it be.  It simply means that others did not find that this answer was a good match for the question being asked.  You can (if you want) delete your answer (if you also agree it is off base and not going to help others), or leave it go.  There's no harm either way.  Contrats on taking the first step, and I look forward to you contributing to answer other questions.